# What can be better option instead of creating index column as Sort by column feature is not working in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am creating graphs in Power BI.

This graph is a line chart with data names – ‘key’, ‘Cumulative Volume’ and ‘Cumulative Gross Profit’.

To calculate both Cumulative, ‘key’ needs to be ordered in decreasing ‘Gross Profit’.
I don’t want to calculate cumulative in Power BI. I want them to be calculated at a data source for good efficiency. Once calculated at source, how can I sort the visual by ‘key’ in decreasing order of ‘Gross Profit’?

Sort by column feature is not working, I’ve tried it already.
For now, I do it by creating an additional column called ‘index’ in decreasing order of ‘Gross Profit’. But I have other similar graphs also and it is maybe not a good practice to create index columns at the source side.

Thank you.

| Key | Volume | Gross Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 200 | 52 |
| 35 | 566 | 95 |
| 74 | 888 | 32 |
| 89 | 600 | 54 |

I want to make Graph C, but I m getting graph B or A.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Bq0.png)

Comment: It will be better if you can show your expected output, cannot really understand your issue here.

Comment: I fully agree with Kin Siang. You are saying Sort by Column is not working so you are looking for a workaround. I would advise you to tell us why you thing sort by column is not working..

Comment: Both Volume and Gross Profit are calculated at source?